# How do you orient a girder in Worms Reloaded?

Tags: worms-reloaded

In older worms games it was possible to rotate and resize the girder before placing it, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in the new game.  Is this still possible?  If so, how?  I looked through the default controls and there didn't seem to be any mention of the girder.

Comment: I know Z alters the fuse of grenades and the direction of airstrikes... but I'm not sure about girders. Edit: 'Z' does not work. Only 'Enter'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Press whatever you have bound to 'Jump.' By default, that'd be 'Enter'.

Comment: Does this still allow you to cycle to longer girders and then back down to shorter ones?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the case no. Girder length seems to be fixed now. :(

Comment: Dang, well I suppose that's what the Bridge Building Kits are for then

Comment: It's very strange that they picked 'Enter' rather than 'Z', which is used for most other kinds of weapon modification.

Answer (score 0):

Use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to change its position.